# GetItemById throws ServerException

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, splistitem, splist

I'm trying to retrieve an item from a list, just for demo purposes. But, when I try to do that, I'm getting a `ServerException` on the `ExecuteQuery()`.

This is the exception:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
```

And this is the code:

```
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web.CurrentUser);
var lists = clientContext.Web.Lists;
clientContext.Load(lists);

var spList = lists.GetById(Guid.Parse(SPListId));
clientContext.Load(spList);

var spListItem = spList.GetItemById(7);
clientContext.Load(spListItem);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I've narrowed the problem down to the `GetItemId(SPListItemId)` method. I'm quite sure that there is an item with the given `SPListItemId`, cause when I open the properties of the specified file, I see that the `ID` parameter is 7.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you also make sure that the SPListId used in code and the list you checked are the same?

Comment: I can verify that. The ID is the same as listed in the "Library Settings" url.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what the issue was. For those coming by later, here's what I did.

The problem was due to a lack of permissions in my Add-In. The Add-In needs minimal permissions to "List" "Read" in your App Manifest. Hope this helps.